# Doors don't lock with keyfob or exterior door handles

Tags: hyundai, key, trunk, power-door-lock

https://imgur.com/a/RN3kFqa

This is what happens when I use the keyfob to lock and unlock the vehicle. It doesn't actually lock anything on the 16 Genesis. Same thing happens when I am using the exterior door handle. I can control the locks with a scanner and interior buttons but using a keyfob or exterior handle it does not perform the locking action.

I took it to the Hyundai dealership, paid a diagnostic fee and they couldn't figure it out either.

This issue occurred when I replaced the power trunk handle (due to silicone deteriorating on the handle). The first thing I noticed after replacing (which it's a plug and play part) is that the trunk wouldn't open. I had to use the vehicle's physical key to unlock the trunk. That's when I noticed the doors don't lock via keyfob.

I have tried reinserting the original power handle, it doesn't fix anything.

I have disconnected the car battery to perform a reset and it does nothing besides what you can see in the video. After about 24-48 hours, when I hit the lock button it won't even turn on the headlights (as seen in video).

My power handle deteriorated previously and I replaced it on this same vehicle with 0 issues. I am not sure why a problem occurred this time when I had to replace the handle again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Seems to me that the Hyundai dealer still owes you a diagnosis for the fee you paid. They *must* escalate to their regional or corporate dealership tech support network. Don't accept a bewildered shrug as an diagnosis. Either that or demand a refund and take it to another Hyundai or Genesis dealer.

Comment: From review: Can you add your external image to an inline image, so we don't have to click on an external link to see it? Thanks!